# Get id from Repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms

i have question 
how to get each ID from this code with Jquery OR javascript?? 
i want to get text one by one to show detail for each please help.

my Jquery Script :

```
<script>
    function myselectFun() {
        var select1 = $("[id=NewsDate]").text().trim();
        alert(select1);
    }
</script>
```

My Html tag:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt4News" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >
    <ItemTemplate>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 NewsLables">
        <div class="text-center NewsDatePadding">
            <span class="PS-BYekanDateLastNews"  id="NewsDate" onclick="myselectFun()">
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewsDate").ToString()%></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please don't use IDs multiple times on your side. Use a class for that

Comment: this isn't MVC, this is webforms. Please use the correct tags

Comment: i use class - same result

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function myselectFun() {
        var select1 = $("[name='Name_NewsDate']");
        
}
```

```html
<span class="PS-BYekanDateLastNews"  name="Name_NewsDate" id="NewsDate" onclick="myselectFun()">
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewsDate").ToString()%></span>
</div>
```